# How to close an expandable table view row when another one is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to prevent having multiple table view cells opened at the same time. I purposefully gave you the whole code so you can try it out by yourself, it's really weird.

Here's the code for the tableview :

```
struct CellDataModel {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    var isExpanded = false
    
    static let mockedData: [CellDataModel] = [
        CellDataModel(title: "Title1", description: "Desc1"),
        CellDataModel(title: "Title2", description: "Desc2"),
        CellDataModel(title: "Title3", description: "Desc3")
    ]
}

class ExpandableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    static let reuseIdentifier = "ExpandableTableViewCell"

    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        ///
        return stackView
    }()

    let mainStackView: UIStackView = {
        ///
        return mainStackView
    }()

    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        ///
        return titleLabel
    }()

    let chevronImageView: UIImageView = {
        ///
        return chevronImageView
    }()

    let expandableView: UIView = {
        ///
        return expandableView
    }()

    let descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
        ///
        return descriptionLabel
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        [mainStackView, expandableView].forEach { stackView.addArrangedSubview($0) }
        [titleLabel, chevronImageView].forEach { mainStackView.addArrangedSubview($0) }
        expandableView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
        setConstraints()
    }

    func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ///
        ])
    }

    func set(_ model: CellDataModel) {
        titleLabel.text = model.title
        descriptionLabel.text = model.description
        expandableView.isHidden = !model.isExpanded
        chevronImageView.image = (model.isExpanded ? UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down") : UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right"))?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
}
```

And here's the code in the view controller :

```
extension HelpVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dataSource[indexPath.row].isExpanded.toggle()
        questionsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ExpandableTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? ExpandableTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        cell.set(dataSource[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dataSource.count
    }
    
}
```

I built the whole table view cell, everything works, except that I can't figure out how to close a cell without having the user to click on it. The problem is that if in the didSelectRowAt function, if I add `dataSource[2].isExpanded == true // or false` (let's say I want the third row to close when I click on any of the rows), it doesn't work. This line just allows the third row to be closed, but the user HAS to click on the third row to make it disappear. It just allows its disapperance. I can't find a way to get a row to close without the user having to specifically click on it.

UPDATE : you need to use `questionsTableView.reloadData` instead of `questionsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't "a line of code" to do what you want. You need to design an app that implements the UI you have in mind.

If you are sure that you only ever want one cell to expand, you may want to set up your model to have an Optional value `expandedRow`. In your `cellForRowAt` method, you'd check to see if it's nil. If nil, you would not build any of your cells as expanded. If it had a non-nil value, you'd build the cell at that index in the expanded form and all others in the non-expanded form.

I'd also say that when the user triggers the action to expand a cell, you'd remember the old value of `expandedRow`, change it, and then tell the table view to update both the old row (if any) and new expanded row.

No, I don't have a line of code to give you. You don't show the model you use, or what you do with your `isExpanded` property.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to approach expand/collapse cells, but...

Assuming your `func set(...)` in your table view cell properly configures the cell for expanded or not, here is just one approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    // toggle the isExpanded property of your data element
    //  for the just-selected row
    dataSource[indexPath.row].isExpanded.toggle()
    
    // loop through ALL elements of your data
    for i in 0..<dataSource.count {
        // if it is NOT the selected row
        if i != indexPath.row {
            // set isExpanded to false
            //  this will "close" any other row that is expanded
            dataSource[i].isExpanded = false
        }
    }
    
    // reload the talbe data
    tableView.reloadData()
    
}
```

---

**Edit** - here is a complete example:

```
struct MyDataStruct {
    var text: String = ""
    var isExpanded: Bool = false
}

class ExpandableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    static let reuseIdentifier: String = "ExpandableTableViewCell"
    
    let label = UILabel()
    
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        heightConstraint = label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        // this avoids inconsequential auto-layout wranings
        heightConstraint.priority = .required - 1

        // so we can see the framing
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    func set(_ d: MyDataStruct) {
        label.text = d.text
        heightConstraint.constant = d.isExpanded ? 100.0 : 50.0
    }
    
}

class ExpandableTestVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    var dataSource: [MyDataStruct] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
        
        // generate some sample data
        for i in 0..<30 {
            let d: MyDataStruct = MyDataStruct(text: "Data for row \(i)", isExpanded: false)
            dataSource.append(d)
        }
        
        tableView.register(ExpandableTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ExpandableTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ExpandableTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ExpandableTableViewCell
        cell.set(dataSource[indexPath.row])
        // avoid the "selection flash"
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // toggle the isExpanded property of your data element
        dataSource[indexPath.row].isExpanded.toggle()
        
        // loop through ALL elements of your data
        for i in 0..<dataSource.count {
            // if it is NOT the selected row
            if i != indexPath.row {
                // set isExpanded to false
                //  this will "close" any other row that is expanded
                dataSource[i].isExpanded = false
            }
        }
        
        // reload the table data
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: when you set Expanded to false and say that it will "close" any other row that is expanded, it does not work. `dataSource[indexPath.row].isExpanded.toggle()` works, but `dataSource[2].isExpanded = false` doesn't do anything

Comment: @JOHNY - then there must be something in your code that you haven't shown us. I added an **Edit** to my answer, with a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made another question that's more detailed, with my whole code, but I think I found the solution : after `dataSource[2].isExpanded = false` for example, instead of writing `TableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` I need to write `tableView.reloadData()` as you did in your answer. Thank you so much i've spent days on this

Comment: I deleted the other question because I guess it's not a good thing the ask the same thing twice

Comment: I edited the question instead

Comment: @JOHNY - did this solve your issue?